# What are the best uses for the Django Admin app?

Tags: python, django, admin

On the website, it says this:

> One of the most powerful parts of
>   Django is the automatic admin
>   interface. It reads metadata in your
>   model to provide a powerful and
>   production-ready interface that
>   content producers can immediately use
>   to start adding content to the site.
>   In this document, we discuss how to
>   activate, use and customize Django’s
>   admin interface.admin interface.

So what? I still don't understand what the Admin interface is used for.  Is it like a PHPMYADMIN? Why would I ever need this?

Comment: You can't imagine any circumstance in which you would need a simple front end to enter information into your db? Really?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you create a model called Entry. IE an extremely simple blog. You write a view to show all the entries on the front page. Now how do you put those entries on the webpage? How do you edit them?

Enter the admin. You register your model with the admin, create a superuser and log in to your running webapp. It's there, with a fully functional interface for creating the entries.

Comment: I would create ./templates/blog.html ...and run this code { for p in posts %} p.title {% endfor %}...is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: If you have another issue you should probably make a new question.

Comment: That is how you *present* the entries from your database. But how do you enter those entries **into** the database to begin with? Enter Admin app...

Answer (score 1):

Some of the uses I can think of -

1. **Editing data** or Adding data. If you have any sort of data entry tasks, the admin app handles it like a breeze. Django’s admin especially shines when non-technical users need to be able to enter data.
2. If you have understood above point, then this makes it possible for programmers to work along with designers and content producers!
3. **Permissions** - An admin interface can be used to give permissions, create groups with similar permissions, make more than one administrators etc. (i.e. if you have a login kinda site).
4. **Inspecting data models** - when I have defined a new model, I call it up in the admin and enter some dummy data.
5. **Managing acquired data** - basically what a moderator does in case of auto-generated content sites.
6. **Block out buggy features** - Also if you tweak it a little, you can create an interface wherein say some new feature you coded is buggy. You could disable it from admin interface.

Think of the power this gives in a big organization where everyone need not know programming.